# MongoDB - Remove object from SubArray

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to remove an object from a subarray with no luck getting `updateOne()` is not a function and `remove()` is not function.

I want to remove the `'subcat 1'` object with id of `'61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ef'`:

```
[
 {
     _id: '61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ee'
     title: 'category 1',
     SubCats: [
         {
             _id: '61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ef'
             name: 'subcat 1',
             image: '/assets/images/vr-box-6203301_1920.jpg',
         },
         {
             _id: '61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748fb'
             name: 'subcat 2',
             image: '/assets/images/galaxy-s20_highlights_kv_00.jpg',
         },
     ]
 },
]
```

Please help

**Controller**:

```
const deleteSubCategory = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
 const subCategory = await Category.aggregate([
     { $unwind: "$SubCats" }, 
     { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$SubCats'} }, 
     { $match: { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }}
 ])

 if (subCategory) {
     await subCategory.updateOne({ $pull: {_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}})
    res.json({ message: 'sub-category removed' })
 } else {
     res.status(404)
     throw new Error('sub-Category not found')
 }
})
```

Comment: That call to updateOne doesn't look right.  Check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne and https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne  Perhaps log the result of the updateOne call for debugging

Comment: subCategory will be an array of documents, which won't have an updateOne function.  I think the answer to your previous question was suggesting that you call `updateOne` instead of `aggregate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$update` with `$pull`

```
db.collection.update({
  "SubCats._id": "61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ef"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    SubCats: {
      _id: "61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ef"
    }
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2sYJTw3u7Fr)